# Firebird ibase_trans() very slow PHP

Tags: php, apache, transactions, firebird

When I'm use ibase_trans() the script start infinite loop and don't respond.

I'am requesting nusoap webservice.
If I just print the nusoap data the script execution time is 3 seconds, after I uncomment the line that start transaction it starts infinite loop.

```
$dbh1 = ibase_connect(DB_HOST1, DB_USER1, DB_PASS1) or die('die message');
$tr1  = ibase_trans($dbh1);
```

After the nusoap data loop I have those lines :

```
$query3    =   ibase_query($tr1,"INSERT INTO EXECUTAR ( FLAG ) VALUES ( 2 )") or die('teste');
```

Here start the problem.

```
My php version : 5.6
Xampp version: 3.2.1
Firebird: 2.5
```

Full code :

```
 if ($client->fault) {
    echo "<h2>Fault</h2><pre>";
    print_r($result);
    echo "</pre>";
} else {
    $error = $client->getError();
    if ($error) {
        echo "<h2>Error.</h2><pre>" . $error . "</pre>";
    } else {

$dbh1 = ibase_connect(DB_HOST1, DB_USER1, DB_PASS1) or die('die message');
            $tr1 = ibase_trans($dbh1);

            $TotalProdutos = 0; 
            foreach($result['ConsultaEstoqueProdutosResult']['diffgram']['NewDataSet']['Estoques'] as $produto){
                $TotalProdutos++;
                $query1    =   ibase_query($tr1,"INSERT INTO ATUALIZA_PRE ( CODIGO,
                                                                                ESTOQUE,
                                                                                ATIVO,
                                                                                DISPONIVEL,
                                                                                ESTOQUEDISPONIVEL,
                                                                                PRECOSEMST,
                                                                                PRECOREVENDA )
                                                                            VALUES ( 
                                                                                '{$produto['CODIGO']}',
                                                                                '{$produto['ESTOQUE']}',
                                                                                {$produto['ATIVO']},
                                                                                {$produto['DISPONIVEL']},
                                                                                {$produto['ESTOQUEDISPONIVEL']},
                                                                                {$produto['PRECOSEMST']},
                                                                                '".$produto['PRECOREVENDA']."')")or die('teste1');

            }


            $dbh1         = ibase_connect(DB_HOST1, DB_USER1, DB_PASS1) or die('die message');
            $tr1        = ibase_trans($dbh1);
            $query3     =   ibase_query($tr1,"INSERT INTO EXECUTAR ( FLAG ) VALUES ( 2 )") or die('teste');
            ibase_commit($tr1);
            ibase_close($dbh1); 
    }
}
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: There is no such thing as Firebird 2.4, are you using 2.1 or 2.5? Could you also include your entire code, because I don't understand what you mean with "After the nusoap data loop"; is that the thing that is going into an infinite loop?

Comment: I've updated the topic

Comment: Could the problem be that you forget to commit the transaction after the loop: you create a new transaction without committing the first transaction. You also unnecessarily create a new connection. Other than that you should really be using parametrized queries. As it stands you are open to SQL injection. However I do not see anything that would explain an infinite loop (but then again, I don't know PHP that well).

Comment: Try to stop using ibase_trans. Use ibase_query($dbh1, ...  and ibase_commit($dbh1).